# How to add value to a struct within a struct

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have the following structs:

```
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x00, 0x2A, 0x7C};

typedef struct struct_message {
  int request_type;
  char message[100];
  float thermal_data[NUMBER_OF_THERMALCOUPLE];
} struct_message;
    
    
typedef struct struct_parameter {
  struct_message *message;
  uint8_t broadcastAddress;
  char label[10];
} struct_parameter;


struct_parameter parameter_Data;
```

And then in `setup()` method I set the following:

```
memcpy(&parameter_Data.broadcastAddress, broadcastAddress, sizeof(broadcastAddress));
strcpy(parameter_Data.label , "123454");
```

Then in `loop()` I print this value:

```
Serial.println(data.label);
```

And evertything works great, but when I want to set a property for the `struct_message` my board reboots.

```
parameter_Data.message->request_type = 1;
```

Any clue? I might be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a pointer to a `struct_message` in your `struct_parameter`. There's no storage allocated for the `struct_message` unless you explicitly allocate it and the pointer will either be 0 or some random number. So when you try to set `request_type` in the message, you're writing to a random location in memory - which causes the crash.

The better option is to just have the `struct_message` be a member of `struct_parameter`, rather than use a pointer to it.

```
typedef struct struct_parameter {
      struct_message message;
      uint8_t broadcastAddress;
      char label[10];
    } struct_parameter;
```

Dropping the `*` tells C++ to put the entire `struct_message` inside `struct_parameter` rather than just a pointer it.

Then you would later write:

```
parameter_Data.message.request_type = 1;
```

This saves you needing to manage memory for `message`.